# Kitty Terminal and sed command: how to escape characters in a complex string?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, terminal, kitty

I want to automatize some code and I would like when I execute my bash script on KITTY, split in 2 panes more.

I did that with the next code:

```bash
cd ~/projects/Project1 && ng s -o &

kitty @ launch sh -c "cd ~/projects/Project2 && npm run dev"
kitty @ launch sh -c "cd ~/projects/Project && npm run dev"
```

Then I wanted to complicated a little bit more and change a connection string of a file.
My connection string looks like this:

```
Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Testing;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;TrustServerCertificate=True;
```

and I want to replace it for something like this:

```
Data Source=localhost;Database=Testing123;User Id=sa;Password=MyPassword/*-432;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Encrypt=false;
```

I did this code with `sed` and works. If I put directly in the terminal (it's replacing the line)

```bash
sed -i 's/Server=\.\\\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Testing;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;TrustServerCertificate=True;/Data Source=localhost;Database=Testing123;User Id=sa;Password=MyPassword\/*-432;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Encrypt=false;/g' ~/projects/Project1/appsettings.json
```

My problem is when I'm trying to use with Kitty, I'm sending all the comannds but I cannot make it works. Something like this:

```bash
kitty @ launch sh -c "sed -i 's/Server=\.\\\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Testing;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;TrustServerCertificate=True;/Data Source=localhost;Database=Testing123;User Id=sa;Password=MyPassword\/*-432;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Encrypt=false;/g' ~/projects/Project1/appsettings.json && cd ~/projects/primereact && npm run dev"
```

Any help?
The final goal is execute the script and open in the same terminal splitted in 3 but in one of them, replace the connecting string.

I hope be clear, thanks for your time!

Comment: it looks to me like it should work. Are you trying to do the sed command for both panes? They're both overwriting the same file, and they may interfere with each other.

Comment: Does `sh -c "sed ....` do what you want without the additional `kitty @ launch` complexity at the start of it? If not then debug that `sh -c` command  first. Also, can't you come up with a much simpler, briefer command that fails (i.e. a [mcve]) and debug that instead of the lengthy pipeline you're currently trying to debug?

Comment: Hi @Barmar, no, only for one pane. And it's not working if I put inside kitty.

Comment: Hi @EdMorton I tried changing one simple word for the connection string and works. The problem is escape of the special characters in my opinion. I tried in different ways for hours and finally I decided to write here.

Comment: Try doubling all the backslashes.

Comment: I did. If you check the original code start like this `.\\SQLEXPRESS` and I changed to `\.\\\\SQLEXPRESS` and same in the rest. I don't know what more can I try. And the docs of ktty it's not clear for me https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/remote-control/ and https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/launch/

Comment: I understand the problem, I'm asking if you can turn it into a smaller, simpler problem by a) Removing `kitty @ launch` and b) Reducing the script so `sed 's/\\SQL//'` or similar and still have the problem.

Comment: That way you/we would be debugging a small, simple script (a [mcve]) something like `sh -c "sed 's/\\SQL//' file"` instead of trying to figure out what's happening somewhere deep in the bowels of `kitty @ launch sh -c "sed -i 's/Server=\.\\\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Testing;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;TrustServerCertificate=True;/Data Source=localhost;Database=Testing123;User Id=sa;Password=MyPassword\/*-432;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Encrypt=false;/g' ~/projects/Project1/appsettings.json && cd ~/projects/primereact && npm run dev"`

Comment: Sorry @EdMorton I tried to be very specific. I tried to do something easier again doing this: `sh -c "sed -i 's/\\.\\\\SQL\\/CHANGED/g' ~/Desktop/from-file.sh"` (in my file I have `.\\SQL`) and It's not working. But if I do this `sh -c "sed -i 's/SQL/CHANGED/g' ~/Desktop/from-file.sh"` (in my file I have `SQL`) works perfectly. I have problems escaping from the backslash  or I don't know if the spaces are the problems too. If this information should be in the main post, let me know and I can write there. Sorry again and thanks for your patience and try to help

Comment: OK, that's a big improvement in the complexity of the script you're asking for help to debug and it should now be reproducible by anyone rather than just people who have whatever "kitty" is so update your question to make it be about that much smaller, simpler problem/code and then I expect you'll get an answer quickly. By the way, in any sed script don't use `/` as the sed delimiter when your regexp includes `/`, pick some other char for the delimiter, i.e. don't do `s/foo\/bar/whatever/`, do `s:foo/bar:whatever:` or `s#foo/bar#whatever#` or pick some other character.

Comment: Oh, and also add to your question a small (2 or 3 lines) file of sample input and the expected output after you run your script on that input to complete the [mcve] and make your problem very easy to reproduce/debug.

Comment: take a look at my [mquote (magic quote)](https://github.com/clarkwang/magic-aliases). it can help you quote properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like this is what you're trying to do:

Sample input:

```
$ cat file
Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS; must change
Server=x\\SQLEXPRESS; must not change
```

Expected output (by running sed without the `sh -c`):

```
$ sed 's/\.\\\\SQLEXPRESS/CHANGED/' file
Server=CHANGED; must change
Server=x\\SQLEXPRESS; must not change

$ sed 's/[.][\][\]SQLEXPRESS/CHANGED/' file
Server=CHANGED; must change
Server=x\\SQLEXPRESS; must not change
```

And now if we add `-c` we get:

Fail:

```
$ sh -c "sed 's/\.\\\\SQLEXPRESS/CHANGED/' file"
Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS; must change
Server=x\\SQLEXPRESS; must not change
```

Pass 1:

```
$ sh -c "sed 's/\\.\\\\\\\\SQLEXPRESS/CHANGED/' file"
Server=CHANGED; must change
Server=x\\SQLEXPRESS; must not change
```

Pass 2:

```
$ sh -c "sed 's/[.][\][\]SQLEXPRESS/CHANGED/' file"
Server=CHANGED; must change
Server=x\\SQLEXPRESS; must not change
```

You just have to either put whatever you want to be treated literally
inside a bracket expression `[...]` or if you choose to escape it by preceding with `\` then you need to double the backslashes when adding a calling extra layer like `sh -c` which will add an extra pass of interpretation of the script.

I personally typically use `\` when I only need 1 backslash or `[...]` if I'd need 2 or more backslashes as I think the resulting code is clearer and simpler.

Now that the problem is clear, here's what you were originally asking to do (without the "kitty launch" stuff which I don't have and I think is probably irrelevant):

```
$ cat file
Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Testing;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;TrustServerCertificate=True;
```

```
$ sh -c "sed 's/Server=[.][\][\]SQLEXPRESS;Database=Testing;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;TrustServerCertificate=True;/Data Source=localhost;Database=Testing123;User Id=sa;Password=MyPassword\/*-432;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Encrypt=false;/g' file"
Data Source=localhost;Database=Testing123;User Id=sa;Password=MyPassword/*-432;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Encrypt=false;
```

Comment: works perfectly!!! thanks a lot for your help, patience and explanation. Was very clear and works perfectly!!! I'm very happy with this solution and now I know better ways to escape with special characters. Thanks a lot!!